# SQL to get last reply of certain user type

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal I need is to get tickets where the last reply is from a user not an admin and the last reply was made 10 days or more. I currently have a SQL that gets the last reply but I'm having a hard time filtering users from admins. My current SQL is:

```
SELECT
    t.tid, tr.reply_date, tr.rid, u.display_name, u.user_type
FROM ticket t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        tr_last.tid, tr_last.reply_date, tr_last.rid, tr_last.uid
    FROM ticket_reply tr_last 
    ORDER BY tr_last.reply_date DESC
) tr ON tr.tid = t.tid
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.uid = tr.uid
WHERE 
    t.status != "Closed"
    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) >= tr.reply_date
GROUP BY t.tid;
```

This returns something like:

```
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| tid   | reply_date          | rid   | display_name                | user_type |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|  6784 | 2012-03-27 04:11:52 | 40061 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8094 | 2013-01-18 21:13:56 | 65037 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8165 | 2012-09-10 14:59:17 | 52956 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8171 | 2012-06-18 19:05:19 | 46527 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8313 | 2012-08-16 23:05:51 | 51362 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8436 | 2012-08-16 23:20:20 | 51368 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8453 | 2012-06-26 23:41:37 | 47247 | (hidden)                    | admin     |
|  8712 | 2012-11-22 10:33:05 | 59697 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8911 | 2013-09-24 00:52:27 | 89910 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8949 | 2013-09-02 16:29:22 | 87718 | (hidden)                    | user      |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

If I add `u.user_type = "user"` in the `WHERE` clause, it changes what row in the `tr` it retrieves so the user from the `6784` `tid` row now shows a user not an admin but the last reply for that ticket is actually an admin. So this:

```
SELECT
    t.tid, tr.reply_date, tr.rid, u.display_name, u.user_type
FROM ticket t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        tr_last.tid, tr_last.reply_date, tr_last.rid, tr_last.uid
    FROM ticket_reply tr_last 
    ORDER BY tr_last.reply_date DESC
) tr ON tr.tid = t.tid
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.uid = tr.uid
WHERE 
    t.status != "Closed"
    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) >= tr.reply_date
    AND u.user_type = "user"
GROUP BY t.tid;
```

now returns this:

```
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| tid   | reply_date          | rid   | display_name                | user_type |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|  6784 | 2012-03-26 23:19:52 | 40051 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8094 | 2013-01-18 18:53:33 | 65016 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8165 | 2012-09-07 01:17:28 | 52831 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8171 | 2012-06-18 19:05:19 | 46527 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8313 | 2012-08-09 18:37:35 | 50776 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8436 | 2012-08-16 23:01:28 | 51359 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8453 | 2012-06-21 16:29:24 | 46843 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8712 | 2012-11-22 10:33:05 | 59697 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8911 | 2013-09-24 00:52:27 | 89910 | (hidden)                    | user      |
|  8949 | 2013-09-02 16:29:22 | 87718 | (hidden)                    | user      |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

You can notice the `rid` column values are different as well.

So my question is, how do I properly return users for this?

Comment: If you do not care much about performance, add `HAVING u.user_type = "user"`

Comment: Turns out I'm actually having the same issue with the `AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) >= tr.reply_date` so it's not actually returning the last reply

Comment: Post your sample data and the expected result, or (even better) set it up in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the last reply anywhere. In your subquery you are just sorting the values.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.tid, tr.reply_date, tr.rid, u.display_name, u.user_type
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT tr_last.tid, tr_last.reply_date, tr_last.rid, tr_last.uid
  FROM ticket_reply tr_last
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tid, max(reply_date)
    FROM ticket_reply
    GROUP BY tid
    ) tr2 ON tr2.tid = tr_last.tid AND tr_last.reply_date = tr2.reply_date
  ) tr ON tr.tid = t.tid
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.uid = tr.uid AND u.user_type = "user"
WHERE t.STATUS != "Closed"
  AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) >= tr.reply_date;
```

The inner query returns the tid and their MAX(date), and gives the most recent reply information.

(I haven't tested this, but looks like what you are looking for).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, just had to make 1 small tweak `MAX(reply_date) as reply_date`